# Two functions compile with type annotations. Remove one annotation - doesn't compile. Remove two - compiles again. Why?

Tags: haskell, types, type-systems

Mind this Reflex program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, RecursiveDo #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Prelude hiding (div)
import Reflex.Dom
import qualified Data.Map as M

clickMe :: MonadWidget t m => m (Event t ())
clickMe = do
    rec (e,_) <- elAttr' "button" M.empty (display c)
        c :: Dynamic t Int <- count (domEvent Click e)
    return $ domEvent Click e

div :: forall t m a . MonadWidget t m => m a -> m a
div = elAttr "div" ("style" =: "border : 1px solid black")

app :: forall t m . MonadWidget t m => m ()
app = div $ do
    aClicks <- clickMe
    bClicks <- clickMe
    a <- count aClicks
    b <- count bClicks
    l <- combineDyn (\a b -> replicate (a-b) ()) a b
    simpleList l (const clickMe)
    return ()

main = mainWidget app
```

If you remove the type annotation from either `div` or `app`, the program won't compile with a huge, scary type error. **If you remove both, it will compile again.** From a programmer's perspective, this gives a terrible user experience when someone is trying to incrementally annotate an unannotated program. It makes no sense that adding a correct type annotation to an unannotated term causes a compiler error, and it leads the programmer to think he got the type wrong.

[This is the error you get by removing `div`'s annotation.](http://lpaste.net/147579)

[Those are the inferred types.](http://lpaste.net/147580)

Why this happens?

Comment: What are the inferred types when you remove the types? How do they compare with the provided types ? This is a speculation but I think one of the inferred or provided types were not generic enough and hence rendered incompatible. Also adding the inferred types could help answering the question.

Comment: I've included the inferred types on the question now, although I can not understand them as there are spiders.

Comment: monomorphism restriction

Comment: Does removing `app`'s type annotation really cause an error? Monomorphic things can call polymorphic things, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to to the monomorphism restriction. When the compiler is typechecking a top-level binding without a type annotation, it will not assign a polymorphic type if that type has a constraint and the function has no syntactic argument, which is the case for *both* of your functions.

However, if you include *neither* type signature, it still doesn't compile. In your case, you gave it some extra information (the `foo = [app, _]` part) and for some reason it chose to pick a monomorphic type - I don't know what changed about your environment but that isn't standard behaviour.

Here is a simple file distilling the issue you are having:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, KindSignatures, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

module Test where 

import Prelude hiding (div)

class MonadWidget t (m :: * -> *) | m -> t 

div :: forall t m a . MonadWidget t m => m a -> m a
div = (undefined :: forall t m a . MonadWidget t m => m a -> m a)

app :: forall t m . MonadWidget t m => m ()
app = (div (undefined :: forall t m . MonadWidget t m => m ())
        :: forall t m . MonadWidget t m => m () )
```

If you comment out either type signature, or both, you will be met with an error.
However, comment out any top-level type signature, but run this with `ghc -XNoMonomorphismRestriction Test.hs` and it will compile successfully in every configuration. [Here](https://ideone.com/GBAcVs) [are](https://ideone.com/iE8Hn2) [a](https://ideone.com/jlciqw) [few](https://ideone.com/PJu2YY) [tests](https://ideone.com/TksLHm).

Comment: Thanks. At this point I think if I should just disable the monomorphism restriction by default.

Answer (score 1):

As Reid Barton noted in comments, this is due to [The Dreaded Monomorphism Restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_Restriction).

Here is simplified example:

```
foo :: Monad m => m a -> m a
foo = (>>= return)

bar :: Monad m => m ()
bar = foo (return ())
```

When monomorphism restriction enabled and `foo`'s type signature commented:

- GHC tries to assign monomorphic type to to `foo` and fails because there is no default `Monad` instance:

> No instance for (Monad m0) arising from a use of ‘>>=’
>      The type variable ‘m0’ is ambiguous

- using `foo` at `bar` leads to another error which I cannot explain

> Couldn't match type ‘m0’ with ‘m’
>        because type variable ‘m’ would escape its scope

Adding `{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}` pragma fixes this and allows to add type signatures incrementally.

Comment: `Adding {-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-} pragma fixes this and allows to add type signatures incrementally.` - Is this always true?

Comment: Yes, if error is caused by monomorphism restriction. On the downside, disabling MR by default can lead to reduced sharing, but this quite rare situation.

Comment: [Here](http://lambda.jstolarek.com/2012/05/towards-understanding-haskells-monomorphism-restriction/) is explanation of how MR affects sharing.

Comment: "but most likely will not stumble upon it in practice" yet I can't count on my fingers how many hours I've lost due to something which ended up being MR's blame... thanks for the link.